# how to degrade version of Phalcon 3.2.2 to version 2

Tags: php, linux, installation, phalcon

From this documentation i have installed the phalcon https://phalconphp.com/en/download/linux

i can that it is successfully installed, but the version is 3.2.2, but i have already inbuilt application which works with version 2..

so i want to degrade the version 3.2.2 to 2 how can i do that.?

this is how i installed:

```
curl -s "https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh" | sudo bash

sudo apt-get install php5-phalcon

# Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-mysql gcc libpcre3-dev
```

Do i need to remove the version 3.2.2.?

then install v 2 please tell uninstalling and installing version 2.?

help is appriciated.

[image]

Comment: with this `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:phalcon/legacy` i need to install version 2 can u help  sourse: https://phalconphp.com/en/download/linux

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/46300234/666599